# BehaviorSubject tells me next is undefined

Tags: angular, undefined, behaviorsubject

In my auth.service.ts file

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { JwtHelperService } from "@auth0/angular-jwt";
import { BehaviorSubject, map, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Role } from '../modal/Role.enum';
import { User } from '../modal/User';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    let localUser = localStorage.getItem('user');
    if (localUser) {
      this.userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localUser));
      this.user = this.userSubject.asObservable();
    }
  }


  public get userValue(): User {
    return this.userSubject?.value;
  }


Login(model: any) {
    return this.httpClient.post(this.url + 'Login', model)
      .pipe(
        map((response: any) => {
          const tokenInfo = response;
          if (tokenInfo && tokenInfo?.data?.token) {
            localStorage.setItem('token', tokenInfo.data.token);
            this.decodedToken = this.JwtHelper.decodeToken(tokenInfo.data.token);
            this.isLogin.next(true);
            this.customerStatus().subscribe((it: any) => {
              let data = it.data;
              const role: Role = (<any>Role)[data.roleCode];
              let user: User = {
                id: data.id,
                firstName: data.firstName,
                lastName: data.lastName,
                email: data.email,
                phoneNumber: data.phoneNumber,
                networkID: data.networkID,
                token: tokenInfo.data.token,
                role: role
              }
              localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
              setTimeout(() => {
                console.log("User")
                console.log(user)
                this.userSubject.next(user); // is undefined here
              }, 1500);
            });
          }
          return response;
        })
      );
  }
```

In my Login method,
this.userSubject.next(user) is undefined here

If I inspect the value for user, it has a valid JSON data.

Pressing Refresh on the browser causes the application to work as expected. But I dont want to tell people to press 'Refresh'

I added the timeout because I thought the userSubject needed a little more time to catch up. It does not seem to be the case.

I am using Angular 14

Comment: Could you share the imports as well on that part of the code ? Sometimes, VSCode would pick up wrong imports

Comment: I am also confused if `next()` method is undefined, or you are actual variable user is undefined. The question and post are saying two different things

Comment: Do you added that for class property like that userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User | null>(null);

Comment: @SonuSindhu if I use <User | null>(null), i get TS Compile errors

Comment: next is undefined. User has a value @Ziyed

Comment: @Ziyed added imports per your request. Thank you

Comment: userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User | null>(null);
user = this.userSubject.asObservable();
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    let localUser = localStorage.getItem('user');
    if (localUser) {
      this.userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(localUser));
      this.user = this.userSubject.asObservable();
    }
  }

like that

Comment: Add `userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null)` outside of the constructor.

Comment: @softwareisfun I would recommend Subject if you don't care the initial value as I see in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what's happening here is the logic for initiating is incorrect

```
let localUser = localStorage.getItem('user');
if (localUser) {
  this.userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(
     JSON.parse(localUser) || { foo: 'hello' }
  );
}
```

This means that if user don't have that in local storage, your subject isn't defined at all.

I think you are better initialising this at first maybe even outside constructor.
And then passing the value in it, or just adding an else in that condition, to make sure it's always initialised.

```
userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);

constructor() {
   this.userSubject.next(...)
}
```

I would also recommend here using ngOnInit, instead of constructor

Comment: If I create a new BehaviorSubject in my Login method, where would the subscription begin?